# Inversing the output of a JSON-request

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have written a macro that sends a JSON request

```
Sub getPrices()

Dim strURL As String, strJSON As String, strTicker As String, strCurrency As String, strLength As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer
Dim http As Object
Dim JSON As Object, Item As Object
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastColumn = .Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
End With


For x = 10 To lastrow

strTicker = Cells(x, 2).Value
strCurrency = Cells(6, 2).Value
strLength = Cells(5, 2).Value
strURL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=" & strTicker & "&tsym=" & strCurrency & "&limit=" & strLength & "&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG"

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", strURL, False
http.Send
strJSON = http.ResponseText
i = 3

Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON)
For Each Item In JSON("Data")
Cells(x, i).Value = Item("close")
i = i + 1

Next
Next

End Sub
```

An example of such a JSON-request is the following output [Example](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG)

The macro obtains the data in such a way that the data of *Today* is located in *LastColumn*. 
The problem with my database in Excel is that all the complimentary data is storaged in the opposite way, where *Today* can be found in *Column A*. I need to align the data. Due to the size of the file, I, ideally, don't want to use *MATCH- and INDEX*-formula's. How can my macro be re-written in such a way that the data is produced from recent --> old instead of old --> recent?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop the collection, `JSON("Data")`, backwards. In this simplified example:

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub getPrices()

    Dim strURL As String, strJSON As String, http As Object, JSON As Object, item As Long

    strURL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG"

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", strURL, False
    http.Send
    strJSON = http.ResponseText

    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON)

    For item = JSON("Data").Count To 1 Step -1   'JSON("Data")(item) <== dictionary
        Debug.Print JSON("Data")(item)("close")
    Next item

End Sub
```

**Example output:**

[image: Close prices in reverse]

**Original response order:**

[image: Original response]

Answer (score 0):

I understand that what you want is to revert sort order in columns. For now the output starts from column 3.

Try changing:

```
i = 3

Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON)
For Each Item In JSON("Data")
Cells(x, i).Value = Item("close")
i = i + 1
```

To:

```
Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON)
i = JSON("Data").Count + 2

For Each Item In JSON("Data")
Cells(x, i).Value = Item("close")
i = i - 1
```